# How to inherit & change a class only for a specific object at initialization?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, anonymous-class

In Java, it is possible to modify the class structure **only for a specific object** at it's initialization:

```
Car ford = new Car(){   
    public float price;  
};
```

Hence, the *ford* object gains a new attribute called price, while other cars don't.

Is there a way I can get similar functionality in C++, without making a entire subclass?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No in C++ you can not do it the way mentioned by you.
You can use anonymous classes to do meet your requirement.

```
class car {
public:
    void test() { cout << "test" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    struct : public car { int price; } fordcar;
    fordcar.test();
    return 0;
}
```

[Live code](http://ideone.com/bZbJM0)

Comment: Can you please use pointers in your answer? I'm bit confused :)

Comment: Confused by _no_ pointers ? Now that's uncommon. And, there's absolutely no need for pointers here.

Comment: If you must use a pointer here, then you need to `typedef` your anonymous class to some name. As mentioned by @Quentin, In `C++`, you won't need a lot of `new` as you do in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible in C++, at least the same way as Java does. But, you can use the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) with a bit more code.

Comment: It is possible with some ad-hoc. But (+1) for mentioning decorator.

Answer (score 0):

> without making a entire subclass?

The thing is, you *are precisely* "making an entire subclass" in your code in Java. (This object has a different class than regular `Car` objects.) It's just that this subclass is an anonymous class. There are no anonymous classes in C++.